# How to install a large cache based program?

Tags: software-installation

I'm very new to Linux and Ubuntu, my professor told me to download two programs for a project we're working on that are direct releases from nasa. and i downloaded their Linux file and it gave me a large cache of folders and files all of the files that say 'install" are text documents and the directions are gibberish to me

Here is where IRAF can be downloaded:

http://iraf.noao.edu/

And here is where DS9 can be downloaded:

http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html

i have no idea how to install these.

Answer (score 4):

From the [installation notes](ftp://iraf.noao.edu/iraf/v216/README) of the 1st link:

```
- I am installing for the First Time:

1)  Create an 'iraf' directory (preferrably /iraf/iraf) and unpack
    the distribution file for your platform there.
2)  Define $iraf in your environment (with a trailing '/')
3)  Run the $iraf/install script to install the system
```

I would do this like this:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/iraf/
```

deals with the 1st bullet point. 3rd party software I always use /opt/ and not the /iraf/iraf/ they suggest. Put the download file into /opt/iraf with `cp ~/Downloads/iraf*.gz /opt/iraf/` and extract it with `cd /opt/iraf/ && tar zfxv iraf*`.

The 2nd bullet point is done with

```
export iraf="/opt/iraf/"
```

If you want this permanent add it in your `.bashrc`. I tend to do this when it all works as expected.

The 3rd bullet point is installing it. There is an "install" script you can start with `cd /opt/iraf && ./install`.

---

Regarding the 2nd link. The README in the download states:

```
cd saods9
unix/configure
make
```

So it is similar to the 1st: create a dir in /opt/ called saods9. Put the download file into that, extract it, then do `./unix/configure` and `make`. If you do not have all the dependencies for `make` install them and re-do the command.

If at any point command complain about permissions: use `sudo`.

Comment: it's starting to make a little sense and im starting to understand this setup a bit. but when i try and do sudo cd /opt/iraf/&& tar zfxv iraf* it tells me there is no command sudo: cd: and without sudo, it "works" but it tells me a whole bunch of "cannot mkdir" and such "permissions denied"

Comment: also for the second file, i have the download and it's extracted into /opt/saods9 but doing ./unix/configure tells me "bash: ./unix/configure: No such file or directory"